# How to forward remote port 3306 to local port in android programmatically with ssh and connect to mysql

Tags: java, android, ssh, jsch, mysql-connector

I want to transfer data from an android SQLite database to a remote mysql database securely. As I can't setup a VPN programmatically I want to transfer the data through an ssh tunnel. I have tried with jkraft.jsch. The forwarding runs without errors, but when I connect with mysql-connector
with

```
conexionMySQL =  DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:53009/",user, password);
```

I get the following error:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Communication link failure: java.io.EOFException, underlying cause: null

** BEGIN NESTED EXCEPTION ** 

java.io.EOFException

STACKTRACE:

java.io.EOFException
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readFully(MysqlIO.java:1395)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.readPacket(MysqlIO.java:1414)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:625)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.createNewIO(Connection.java:1808)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Connection.<init>(Connection.java:452)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:411)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
    at de.damian.android.common.Mysql$2.run(Mysql.java:151)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)


** END NESTED EXCEPTION **
```

The code is:

```
public int connectSSH(int rport)
{

// 
    int assigned_port;
    final int local_port = 53009;

// Remote host and port
    final int remote_port = rport;
    final String remote_host = "test.test.org";

    try
    {
        jsch = new JSch();

// Create SSH session. Port 22 is your SSH port which.   
// is open in your firewall setup.
        session = jsch.getSession("xxx", remote_host, 22);
        session.setPassword("xxxxxx");

// Additional SSH options. See your ssh_config manual for.    
// more options. Set options according to your requirements.
        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties();
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        config.put("Compression", "yes");
        config.put("ConnectionAttempts", "2");

        session.setConfig(config);

// Connect
        session.connect();

// Create the tunnel through port forwarding. 
// This is basically instructing jsch session to send 
// data received from local_port in the local machine to 
// remote_port of the remote_host.  
// assigned_port is the port assigned by jsch for use,
// it may not always be the same as.  
// local_port.

        assigned_port = session.setPortForwardingL(local_port,
                remote_host, remote_port);

    }
    catch (JSchException e)
    {
        Log.e(Level.SEVERE.toString(), e.getMessage(), e);
        return 0;
    }


    if (assigned_port == 0)
    {
        Log.e(Level.SEVERE.toString(), "Port forwarding failed !");
        return 0;
    }
    return assigned_port;
}
```

Comment: If you *"want to transfer data ... **securely**"*, start by **not** setting `config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");`, as you lose any security by doing so.

Comment: At what moment do you call the `DriverManager.getConnection` (in releation to the JSch code)?

Comment: Where's the `session` declared?

Comment: The session is declared as a class field as I have to disconnect it later. The drivermanager.getConnection is called after I get a valid port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is quite simple: setPortForwarding must use "localhost" as hostname as the remoteport is not open on the remote interface and you are already logged in in the remote host.

```
assigned_port = session.setPortForwardingL(local_port,
            "localhost", remote_port);
```